# Count rows between 2 time stamps in table based on a time_stamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I have 2 columns: `start_time`, `end_time`.

It is used for a phone system, every time a call starts its insert a new row with the `start_time` and by the end of the call it updating the `end_time`.

I want to count for each start_time how much calls was live in that time,

Table example:

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | start_time          | end_time            |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 3052 | 2019-03-28 21:40:25 | 2019-03-28 21:42:41 |
| 3053 | 2019-03-28 21:42:26 | 2019-03-28 21:42:59 |
| 3054 | 2019-03-28 21:42:40 | 2019-03-28 21:44:41 |
| 3055 | 2019-03-28 21:45:24 | 2019-03-28 21:45:55 |
| 3056 | 2019-03-28 21:45:26 | 2019-03-28 21:45:42 |
| 3057 | 2019-03-28 21:46:57 | 2019-03-28 21:48:52 |
| 3058 | 2019-03-28 21:47:11 | 2019-03-28 21:47:37 |
| 3059 | 2019-03-28 21:49:12 | 2019-03-28 21:52:19 |
| 3060 | 2019-03-28 21:49:34 | 2019-03-28 21:53:48 |
| 3061 | 2019-03-28 21:50:51 | 2019-03-28 21:51:33 |
| 3062 | 2019-03-28 21:53:51 | 2019-03-28 21:54:07 |
| 3063 | 2019-03-28 21:54:36 | 2019-03-28 21:55:26 |
| 3064 | 2019-03-28 21:55:34 | 2019-03-28 21:56:16 |
| 3065 | 2019-03-28 21:56:05 | 2019-03-28 21:57:28 |
| 3066 | 2019-03-28 21:56:24 | 2019-03-28 21:56:40 |
| 3067 | 2019-03-28 21:58:48 | 2019-03-28 21:59:16 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I would like to get the result like this:

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
| id   | start_time          | end_time            | count |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
| 3052 | 2019-03-28 21:40:25 | 2019-03-28 21:42:41 | 1     |
| 3053 | 2019-03-28 21:42:26 | 2019-03-28 21:42:59 | 2     |
| 3054 | 2019-03-28 21:42:40 | 2019-03-28 21:44:41 | 3     |
| 3055 | 2019-03-28 21:45:24 | 2019-03-28 21:45:55 | 1     |
| 3056 | 2019-03-28 21:45:26 | 2019-03-28 21:45:42 | 2     |
| 3057 | 2019-03-28 21:46:57 | 2019-03-28 21:48:52 | 1     |
| 3058 | 2019-03-28 21:47:11 | 2019-03-28 21:47:37 | 2     |
| 3059 | 2019-03-28 21:49:12 | 2019-03-28 21:52:19 | 1     |
| 3060 | 2019-03-28 21:49:34 | 2019-03-28 21:53:48 | 2     |
| 3061 | 2019-03-28 21:50:51 | 2019-03-28 21:51:33 | 3     |
| 3062 | 2019-03-28 21:53:51 | 2019-03-28 21:54:07 | 1     |
| 3063 | 2019-03-28 21:54:36 | 2019-03-28 21:55:26 | 1     |
| 3064 | 2019-03-28 21:55:34 | 2019-03-28 21:56:16 | 1     |
| 3065 | 2019-03-28 21:56:05 | 2019-03-28 21:57:28 | 2     |
| 3066 | 2019-03-28 21:56:24 | 2019-03-28 21:56:40 | 2     |
| 3067 | 2019-03-28 21:58:48 | 2019-03-28 21:59:16 | 1     |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
```

For each `start_time` the number of calls in same time, so I will know an everage how many channels I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could self-join the table and use aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    t.id, 
    t.start_time,
    t.end_time,
    COUNT(*) cnt
FROM mytable t
LEFT JOIN mytable t1 
    ON t1.start_time <= t.start_time AND t1.end_time >= t.start_time
GROUP BY
    t.id, 
    t.start_time,
    t.end_time
ORDER BY 
    t.id, 
    t.start_time
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6kjvdoCXGETZCWMyVuz1h9/0)**:

```
| id   | start_time          | end_time            | cnt |
| ---- | ------------------- | ------------------- | --- |
| 3052 | 2019-03-28 21:40:25 | 2019-03-28 21:42:41 | 1   |
| 3053 | 2019-03-28 21:42:26 | 2019-03-28 21:42:59 | 2   |
| 3054 | 2019-03-28 21:42:40 | 2019-03-28 21:44:41 | 3   |
| 3055 | 2019-03-28 21:45:24 | 2019-03-28 21:45:55 | 1   |
| 3056 | 2019-03-28 21:45:26 | 2019-03-28 21:45:42 | 2   |
| 3057 | 2019-03-28 21:46:57 | 2019-03-28 21:48:52 | 1   |
| 3058 | 2019-03-28 21:47:11 | 2019-03-28 21:47:37 | 2   |
| 3059 | 2019-03-28 21:49:12 | 2019-03-28 21:52:19 | 1   |
| 3060 | 2019-03-28 21:49:34 | 2019-03-28 21:53:48 | 2   |
| 3061 | 2019-03-28 21:50:51 | 2019-03-28 21:51:33 | 3   |
| 3062 | 2019-03-28 21:53:51 | 2019-03-28 21:54:07 | 1   |
| 3063 | 2019-03-28 21:54:36 | 2019-03-28 21:55:26 | 1   |
| 3064 | 2019-03-28 21:55:34 | 2019-03-28 21:56:16 | 1   |
| 3065 | 2019-03-28 21:56:05 | 2019-03-28 21:57:28 | 2   |
| 3066 | 2019-03-28 21:56:24 | 2019-03-28 21:56:40 | 2   |
| 3067 | 2019-03-28 21:58:48 | 2019-03-28 21:59:16 | 1   |
```

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.start_time <= t.start_time and
              t2.end_time >= t.end_time
       ) as num_concurrent_calls
from t;
```